# Uploading images from Wordpress frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

I am attempting to create a frontend form for users to upload multiple images and attach them to a post.

The post is posting just fine, all the data is attached. But I keep getting these two errors:

```
Warning: Illegal offset type in mysite/wp-admin/includes/media.php on line 254

Warning: Illegal offset type in mysite/wp-admin/includes/media.php on line 255
```

I've been trying this for a long time now and have searched high and low. I cannot seem to get this working. I have simplified the form to only upload one image for now, which that isn't working either. Below is the PHP I am using to process the upload:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');


if ($_FILES) {
     $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $_FILES['upl'], $rid );
     set_post_thumbnail($rid, $attach_id);
     update_post_meta($rid,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
}
```

Where `$rid` is the post ID.

The input field is `<input type="file" name="upl" class="ride_image"/>`

I have already checked my max upload size, and the `$_FILES` global is returning the image properly. Here is an example `var_dump($_FILES);`

```
array(1) { ["upl"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(21) "rizkdbr2live_lead.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpgPwO8W" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(85529) } }
```

Keep in mind, this is the most simplified this form will be. I am just trying to get the image to actually upload right now. I will be adding in validation and things like that.

Any idea what those two `Illegal offset type` errors are and how I can fix them? This is becoming a very, very tedious task which should be pretty easy. Would it be against all standards to write custom PHP outside of wordpress to process this image upload or is using `media_handle_upload()` the only way to really do this? I want to abide by standards as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From wordpress codex:

```
<?php media_handle_upload( $file_id, $post_id, $post_data, $overrides ); ?>

$file_id 
(string) (required) Index into the $_FILES array of the upload
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload

So you need to pass `upl` instead `$_FILE['upl']`

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood that part. Thank you!